# How to assign current class instance in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, this

I have code which looks something like,

```
data class X{
    fun getSomething(){
    var y: Y()
    //How can I write this
    //this=y.doSomething()
    }
}

class Y{
    fun doSomething(): X{ 
    //...
    return x }
}
```

I want to assign `this` to an object that I am returning from some other method in some other class.

Comment: You cannot assign to `this`. What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: @s1m0nw1, I want to make some changes to the current class instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign anything to `this` and also, `data` classes should be immutable. Just reassign your reference:

```
data class X(val x: String) {
    fun getSomething() = Y().doSomething()
}

class Y {
    fun doSomething(): X {
        return X("fromY")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val second = X("first").getSomething()
}
```